# AWS Redshift UNLOAD completes successfully but no data in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to make use of RedShift's UNLOAD to copy some data into S3. My query looks like this:

```
unload ('select ________________')
to 's3://my-bucket-name'
iam_role 'arn #';
```

If I run the select statement on it's own, I get 3 records returned, if I run the query as shown above, it is able to complete but I never see anything show up in my S3 bucket. Is there somewhere where I can find more detailed logs?

Also, the IAM role I'm giving it, is an Admin role that has full access to everything, was planning on getting it to work for a proof of concept and then make/use a role that is better suited. Also, can someone explain the IAM role? Why does it not use the IAM role for me, the user running the query?

Comment: If it was the IAM role it would error, I suspect that the queries not returning any results. Can you try `s3://my-bucket-name/unload` or another prefix name perhaps?

Comment: @mokugo-devops I tried that and same result. I noticed something else however, if I run the SELECT statement on it's own, it completes and in the "query results" window below the query editor I can see the records. If I click on the "Query XXXXX" it takes me to a new window with query details, but it states that no rows were returned (even though in the query results page I can see the rows returned)

Comment: Can you confirm the IAM policy on your AWS role?

Comment: Yes. The Policy is 'AdministratorAccess' which has full access for all resources on both Redshift and S3.

Comment: Is the IAM role used in the command attached to the Redshift cluster? If not, you'll have to do so. Also, ensure that the trust relationship in the role allows Redshift service to assume that role.